# My Photoshop brush strokes look pixelated

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

After a long time of not using PS, today I've noticed a weird behavior with my smooth brush. The strokes look very pixelated, especially when I zoom in on the canvas. I'm using the standard brush.

If you open this image in a new tab, or zoom in on it, you can see the weird lines on the edge of the stroke where it should be seamlessly smooth.

[image: Weird brush behavior]
What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

These are my brush settings:

[image]

Comment: how high is the resolution of your file?

Comment: the resolution is 1440x1080

Comment: PPI not size...

Comment: oh, sorry, PS noob here XD.. 300 Pixels/Inch

Comment: Could be the zoom level, that is 155,9%. Check how it looks if you do 100%.

Comment: Thank you, @Joonas It looks perfect on 100%, but when I'm working on details ot something that requires zoom, it is still annoying...

Comment: If you look at this picture, that was taken on a different computer, the zoom level is 70,47 and the strokes still look smooth. http://imgur.com/a/whQSP

Comment: Okay, I've resolved the problem by updating the GPU drivers and enabling GPU render. Thank you @Joonas for narrowing down the problem. :D

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what is happening and I don't know the technical details, but it may be just the way photoshop renders the image, which is better in my experience if you zoom in even numbers. It's easier if you use the zoom tool. Which you can temporarily activate if you press and hold ctrl+space (for zoom in) or alt+ctrl+space (for zoom out) and just click to zoom in our out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem by updating the GPU drivers and enabling GPU render.

Comment: If you solved your question yourself, please consider marking your own answer as 'accepted'. This is not just good for site stats, but also tells later visitors that this is the solution to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to, but I have to wait 3 days for some reason. At the time I'm writing this, I have to wait 18 more hours, hopefully I won't forget it.

Comment: I don't understand the reason behind the -1, because this DID resolve my problem. The rendering performance is obviously better when it's done by the GPU. Since I'm using the newest version of PS, it didn't recognize the outdated driver, and the rendering was done by the CPU, and that's why zooming in on the canvas made the edges look weird.

Comment: I guess the downvoter downvoted because they thought this a very short answer without any explanation. If you explain a bit more about what and how, you might have a better answer on your hands.

Answer (score 1):

It just looks like a soft edge brush...

Check the brush settings... make sure the `Hardness` is set correctly... make certain `Wet Edges` isn't ticked, all in the **Brushes Panel**.

Comment: I've updated the post, and as the image shows, wet edges isn't ticked, and increasing the hardness didn't help.

Comment: @Sparky The updated image leads to *more* confusion, not less --
 because it contains clearly harder edged brush strokes in addition to softer edged strokes. Quite honestly.. it looks like some strokes are made with a brush.. and some are made with the **Pencil tool**.

Comment: I was trying multiple hardness values, but the pixeliness isn't gone no matter how hard/soft the brush is.

Comment: Well there are pixels.. but I don't see anything out of the ordinary. I mean, your *monitor* has to use pixels to display things and zooming in will **always** make that more apparent. Are you expecting absolutely no indication of pixels?

Comment: The following screenshot is of an older version of PS, from a different computer. The image size is about the same, and if you compare the strokes with the ones on the first two screenshots, there is an obvious difference, the strokes on this image are much smoother.
http://imgur.com/a/whQSP

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really seeing any big difference other than the hardness of the brush. In any event, if things aren't operating as expected.. do some standard troubleshooting.. trash preferences, relaunch application, reboot machine..etc. I'd love to help, but I really am not seeing what you are indicating.

Answer (score -1):

Increase your hardness. It's not pixelated - the hardness controls the edges of the line.